# this.props.onChange returned in render function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am struggling to understand what the assigned onChange property means in the following TextField component (from material-ui library):

```
<TextField style = {{"padding":"10px","width":"100%"}}
           type = {'number'}
           value = {this.props.count.value}
           onChange={(event, newValue) => this.props.onChange(newValue, ID, "count")} />
```

There is no object/data being passed through with  an onChange function attribute... from the higher level component ?

So what does the entire function mean ? It seems very confusing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`onChange` is handled by the `TextField` component. When they invoke the `onChange` function, it gets two arguments, `event` and `newValue`. What your doing is specifying an inline `onChange` handler that uses one of those two arguments to call `this.props.onChange` with the value from the text input and also some other values that are not.

Comment: Thanks. How can I edit this onChange? I am trying to make the textfield so that it does not accept negative numbers. BUt not sure how to do that.